# Capybara Timeout when waiting for S3 images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rspec, capybara

I'm running tests with Capybara and chrome (not headless for debugging) and some of my tests fail with a timeout error:

```
Net::ReadTimeout
```

However, those pages work fine outside of tests. 
When the testing browser is opened on those failing pages, I can always see it waiting for S3 images, which might be causing the timeout.

This issue appeared not long ago, it used to work perfectly fine. 
Any idea on how to fix this ?

Comment: You might check your `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` within your Rspec.configure block. Just bump it up to 120 (2 min) and see if that helps. As an alternative (and performance boost), you may want to stub your calls to S3, then write one test to check that S3 works as you intend.

Comment: Do you have any rate limiting configured?